# Asset linking with gitlab release cli using paramter expansion

Tags: bash, shell, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cd

I was attempting to attach a variable number of releases to a gitlab release by doing the following:

```
# UPLOAD_JARS contains the file paths for the jar files created using maven.
for i in ${UPLOAD_JARS[@]}; 
   do                
   JSON_STRING='{"name":"'"${i}"'","url":"'"${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}${i#*\./}"'"}';                         
   JSON_STRING="'$JSON_STRING'"; 
   ASSET_LINKS+=("--assets-link $JSON_STRING"); 
done
```

This allows me to produce a json string that seems to adhere to the formatting as specified here: [Gitlab Release Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/)

Unfortunately, the problem arises in the following segment where I try parameter expansion to append the command argument to the array elements and add it as an argument to the release-cli command:

```
release-cli create --name "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG" --tag-name $CI_COMMIT_TAG "${ASSET_LINKS[@]/#/--asset-links }"
```

This leads to the following error:

> Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -assets-link

The interesting aspect here is that the error is targeted at the json associated with the ***second release***, which led me to believe that the hyphen was being escaped for the rest of the array elements so I tried to remedy that situation by adding extra hyphens to all "asset-links" after the first one but the error persists. Alternatively, I tried to add a backslash character to the command argument **(\--asset-links)** but to no avail as well.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: If you want to manipulate or create JSON data from a shell script. It is worth using `jq`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `jq` to produce a valid JSON formatted list.

Also check your script use proper double quotes around variables.

Avoid using ALL CAPITAL variable names.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Sample data
# No need to ALL_CAPS variables
package_registry_url='https://packages.example.com/'
upload_jars=('foo bar.jar' 'bar baz.jar' 'baz quux.jar')

# Splits upload_jars into a null delimited stream
# to be processed by jq
printf '%s\0' "${upload_jars[@]}" |
  # jq -slurps -Raw_input stream as a single string
  # and get regURL argument from $package_registry_url bash variable
  jq -Rs --arg regURL "$package_registry_url" '

# Starts JSON array
[

  # Splits null delimited input string into a JSON array
  # and pass elements [] |
  split("\u0000")[] |

  # Build a JSON object
  {

    # "name" property from element .
    "name": .,

    # "url" property from concatenating
    # the $regURL argument +
    # the element . | @uri filtered to be a valid uri
    "url": ( $regURL + (. | @uri) )
  }

# Ends JSON array
]'
```

Actual output from the sample data:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "foo bar.jar",
    "url": "https://packages.example.com/foo%20bar.jar"
  },
  {
    "name": "bar baz.jar",
    "url": "https://packages.example.com/bar%20baz.jar"
  },
  {
    "name": "baz quux.jar",
    "url": "https://packages.example.com/baz%20quux.jar"
  }
]
```

Comment: The issue is not the formulation of the JSON itself since I am able to get a valid JSON using my script as well, which I verified by using echo and then hard-coding it in the parameter list. Also, the outputted JSON in your example does not fit with the release cli guidelines: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/ (see the asset-links section which requires the argument to be repeated). I need a dynamic way for parameter resolution (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and ended up writing the command to be executed to a shell file and then executed this file, as I was unable to run it directly from `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
[... Determine $PACKAGE_ID - out of scope for this demo ...]
  - GITLAB_PAGES=$(curl -s --head "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/${PACKAGE_ID}/package_files?per_page=20" | grep -i "X-Total-Pages" | grep -o -e '[0-9]*')
  - for i in $(seq 1 $GITLAB_PAGES); do
  -   FILES_PAGE=$(curl -s "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/${PACKAGE_ID}/package_files?per_page=${GITLAB_PER_PAGE}&page=$i" | jq -r ".[] | .file_name + \"|\" + (\"${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/${PACKAGE_ID}/package_file/\" + (.id | tostring)) " )
  -   for FILE in $FILES_PAGE; do
  -     FILE_NAME=${FILE%%|*}
  -     FILE_URL=${FILE##*|}
  -     |
        CURRLINK="{ \"name\": \"${FILE_NAME}\", \"url\": \"${FILE_URL}\" }"
  -     if [ -z "$LINKS"]; then
  -       LINKS=$CURRLINK
  -     else
  -       LINKS="$LINKS,$CURRLINK"
  -     fi
  -   done
  - done
  - LINKS="--assets-link='[$LINKS]'"
  - echo $LINKS
  - CMD="release-cli create --tag-name \"${OSVERSION}\"  --ref ${CI_COMMIT_SHA} --name \"${PACKAGE_DESC} ${OSVERSION}\" $LINKS"
  - echo $CMD > ./do-release.sh
  - sh do-release.sh
[...]
```

This retrieves the list of generic package files for the current package and dynamically builds the string with the assets. The complete command is then written to a new file and executed from there.